# A way to sort integers in a list by using a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was wondering if there would be a way to sort a list in order according to the increasing floats as values in a dictionary. I don't really know how to explain it so I'll demonstrate what I mean

```
[3, 6, 4]
```

to

```
[6, 4, 3]
```

with dictionary like this

```
{6: 15.6, 3: 120.0, 4: 17.3}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Try using an `OrderedDict` from the `collection` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: @ScottMcC I don't think that is relevant here.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't read the question correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `key` argument of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> mylist = [3, 6, 4]
>>> mydict = {6:15.6, 3:120.0, 4:17.3}
>>> sorted(mylist, key=mydict.get)
[6, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you don't even need that list as the `dict` keys are sufficient:

```
>>> my_dict = {6: 15.6, 3: 120.0, 4: 17.3}
>>> sorted(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
[6, 4, 3]
```